# MvxRestRequest - Cannot supply Body for request

Tags: mvvmcross

In the MvvmCross Network plugin, if you use the MvxRestRequest class, there isn't a BODY property to attach content to.

```
MvxRestRequest req = new MvxRestRequest("url", "POST");
```

'req' won't have a BODY property.

In my case, when I do a POST and don't supply a body the server returns an error of "Length Required", so the 'Content-Length' header is missing.

To get around the length issue, I tried to add this:

```
request.Headers.Add("Content-Length", "0");
```

But get an error:

```
The 'Content-Length' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
Parameter name: name
```

How do I POST a message with content?

Answer (score 1):

There are several classes that appear to support appending content to the BODY of the request:

```
MvxStringRestRequest
MvxStreamRestRequest
```

Using these DOES provide a BODY property.

```
var req = new MvxStringRestRequest("url", "POST);
req.Body = "some content";
```

Comment: Y - there's some docs on this at https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#network - also for modern `async` apps, you can use `HttpClient` in PCL libraries